Need help solving media type problem doing REST POST from Jenkins script
I'm trying to do a REST POST from a Jenkins pipeline script:
def data = [
    'markdown': params.message,
    'roomId': params.roomid
]

echo "Webex data: ${data}"

def response = httpRequest url: 'https://api.foo.com/v1/messages',
    httpMode: 'POST',
    requestBody: data.toMapString(),
    validResponseCodes: '200,400,401,404,415',
    customHeaders: [
        [name: 'Content-Type', value: "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8"],
        [name: 'Authorization', value: "Bearer ${params.token}"]
    ]

println("Status: ${response.status}")
println("Response: ${response.content}")
println("Headers: ${response.headers}")

The output is:
Status: 415
Response: {"message":"The request was made to a resource without specifying a media type or used a media type that is not supported. 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8' is not included.","errors":[{"description":"The request was made to a resource without specifying a media type or used a media type that is not supported. 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8' is not included."}],"trackingId":"ROUTERGW_dc76a5ab-43cf-4add-8bd2-8fa0302c8836"}
Headers: [Content-Length:[441], Content-Type:[application/json], Date:[Mon, 19 Aug 2024 11:57:23 GMT], Server:[istio-envoy], Trackingid:[ROUTERGW_dc76a5ab-43cf-4add-8bd2-8fa0302c8836, ROUTERGW_dc76a5ab-43cf-4add-8bd2-8fa0302c8836], Vary:[Origin], X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff, nosniff], X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time:[11]]

When I code something similar from a Python script, it works fine:
room_id = 'Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vNTI2YzFlOTAtYmViYi0xMWU5LTkzYWUtNTU1ZTE5YTM2NGQ2'
message = '''I'm a lumberjack and I'm ok'''

resp = requests.post(
    'https://api.foo.com/v1/messages',
    data={
        'roomId': room_id,
        'markdown': message,
    },
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {os.environ["TOKEN"]}'},
)


How can I fix my Jenkins script?

don't send the charset parameter.  application/octet-stream should be sufficient

I think I started out without it.  If I remove it, I got the message "The request was made to a resource without specifying a media type or used a media type that is not supported. 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8' is not included."

in that case, it's possible they don't support octet-stream.  is it expecting application/json?

I don't know.  How would I find out?  At this point, I feel like I'm beating my head bloody against a brick wall and am about to refactor it into a Python script.

do you have control over the service you are trying to call? does it have any documentation available?  Try send the request with application/json or content-type: application/* OR content-type: */*. Lastly, you might try a HEAD or OPTIONS request to see which headers the server responds with that might provide a hint.

No, I don't have control over the server.  I got a request to work and will be answering with details.

I considered refactoring with Python but considering how the code is going to be used in my team's infrastructure and when/where you can run scripts from a Jenkins script, I think that could have been very challenging.
I kept digging with the Jenkins script and hunted for uses by other teams at my company.  Their example gave me some ideas and I got this working:
def data = """
{
    "markdown": "${params.message}",
    "roomId": "${params.roomid}"
}
"""

echo "Webex data: ${data}"
echo "Authorization: Bearer ${params.webex_token}"
            
def response = httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true,
    url: 'https://api.foo.com/v1/messages',
    httpMode: 'POST',
    validResponseCodes: '200,400,401,404,415',
    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
    customHeaders: [
        [name: 'Authorization', value: "Bearer ${params.token}"],
    ],
    requestBody: data

I plan to work on it to allow arbitrary messages.. possibly with embedded double blanks, etc.
